# Forwarding a received call to anothen phone number and record the call – Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

I want to forward a received call to anothen phone number and record the call. How can I do it with Voximplant?

Answer (score 0):

You can forward a received call to another phone number and record the call on Voximplant easily:

```
require(Modules.Recorder);

VoxEngine.addEventListener(AppEvents.CallAlerting, (e) => {
 
   let call2 = VoxEngine.callPSTN(e.destination,""<rented_number>""); 
   VoxEngine.easyProcess(e.call, call2); 

   e.call.record({hd_audio: false, transcribe: false});

});
```